# How to port ExtJS 6 application to material design?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I do not use ExtJS tools like cmd and do not have an app.json file. I'm used to writing code by hand and basically what I have is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ext-6.5.0/build/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ext-6.5.0/build/packages/ux/classic/triton/resources/ux-all.css" type="text/css" />
```

I tried to simply switch to CSS files from "modern" folder, but all my interface just collapsed. So,

How can I do it right?

Comment: are you using extjs classic or modern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How is written here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/guides/core_concepts/material_theme.html)

You need to change your theme requirement on app.json file like this

```
"theme": "theme-material",
```

but keep attention,

the material theme **is now awaiable only if you're using extjs modern toolkit**..

Sencha [in his future roadmap](https://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-product-roadmap-update/) is programming to provide a material theme also for extjs CLASSIC toolkit.

In this moment, to have on Classic Toolkit a material theme, you need to create a personal theme, or edit a disponible one.